# Unwanted white space on right side in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

For my portfolio site I see a white space to the right side in the mobile view(only in chrome) and its fine in desktop and Mozilla mobile view. Here I am attaching the screenshot of it.

[Chrome Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN4C9.jpg)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

#preloader {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
  z-index: 999;
}

.spinner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;

  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 3px solid #f25a41;
  border-radius: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.navbar-default {
  transition: 500ms ease;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default.scrolledDown {
  background: #333333;
}

#navbarContainer {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.active {
  color: #f73c56 !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f73c56 !important;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
} */

h1 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABZJREFUeNpi2r9//38gYGAEESAAEGAAasgJOgzOKCoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #666;
}

.actualText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.typedText {
  color: #e60000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 552px) {
  .banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.4);
    padding: 0%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.4);
    padding: 0%;
  }
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff, #ccc, #fff);
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="55">
    <div id="preloader">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- ----------NAVBAR---------- -->
    <nav
      class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-default navbar-dark"
      id="navbarContainer"
    >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">Tathagat</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarContent"
        aria-label="Toggle Navigation"
        aria-controls="navbar supported content"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div
        class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
        id="navbarContent"
      >
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#homeSection">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutSection">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#workSection">Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#skillsSection">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#timeLineSection">Timeline</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#resumeSection">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contactMe">Contact</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">
              Pause
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- ----------Content---------- -->

    <div class="homeSection" id="homeSection">
      <div class="video-container">
        <video autoplay loop id="bgVideo" poster="./media/bgVideoPoster.png">
          <source src="./media/bgVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="banner">
          <div class="actualText">
            <h1>Hi There !</h1>
            <h1>I am <span class="typedText"></span></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aboutSection mb-4" id="aboutSection">
      <div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col mb-3 spacerClass">
            <h1
              data-aos="fade-down"
              data-aos-delay="50"
              data-aos-duration="2000"
            >
              About Me
            </h1>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div
            class="col-sm-6 p-2 text-center"
            data-aos="fade-right"
            data-aos-delay="50"
            data-aos-duration="2000"
          >
            <img
              src="./media/img/myPhoto.jpg"
              height="300"
              width="300"
              alt="Tathagat Mohanty"
              style="
                -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
              "
            />
          </div>
          <div
            class="col-sm-6 text-center"
            data-aos="fade-left"
            data-aos-delay="50"
            data-aos-duration="2000"
          >
            <h4 class="mt-3">
              Hello this is Tathagat Mohanty. I am a Web Developer by profession
              with 2+ years of experience in this fast paced IT Industry.
            </h4>
            <h5 class="text-muted mt-3">
              I am an astute learner skilled in FrontEnd Technologies. I believe
              Design is something which is very personal and individual. With
              that in mind I try to develop websites for multiple types of end
              users with an approachable and clean design.
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have posted the starting part of the HTML Body and CSS in the snippet for reference.
Can anyone please help me  with the guess whats causing this. I have tried the ghost css method to check if any element is exceeding the viewport width but couldnt find any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the document structure and check what occupies that space.

Comment: Without code, we can't.

Comment: One of your elements will be the cause, but without looking at the code it's very hard to tell. Inspect element and look through each div to see if you can find it. Then if not, delete each top level element in inspect element until the horizontal scroll bar disappears. Then you can gradually find the elements that are causing it.

Comment: I can post my code but which is about 400 lines which is difficult here.

Comment: @fredrivett,when i inspect on my white space its not inscepting on any element.

Comment: @MMR You don't need to post all 400 lines, just a [mcve], the lines that you managed to track down to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @MMR inspect document then delete parent divs one by one then you'll find which causing the problem

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think there might be one element on your page which might have a width and a padding or margin exceeding 100%.
When 'inspecting' the page and hover over the white space you might select an element there which is going outside of the wanted page.

Try and find this using the inspect element and change this in CSS with using media queries

Comment: There was an element whose width is > 100% and that caused this.Thnaks to all.

Comment: Can you point an example scenerio where a width can go more than 100%?

Comment: Thanks, I faced a similar problem, found the offending element where the width was set to 100% with additional padding. Fixed by adding box-sizing: border-box; to the container.

Answer (score 99):

Firstly follow the above answer make sure that the width of any element should not exceed 100% and then also try this:
Try making `overflow-x: hidden;` in html as well

```
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It worked for me

Comment: while without "html," seemed to work on inspection on phone size on pc, the issue still occurred on phone itself, by adding this extra "html," it fixed it on the device too.

Comment: Worked for me. Adding html is advisable.

Comment: wouldn't recommend doing something like this but as @mweb suggested find the element that's breaking your sight.

one possible down-side to this: you might be breaking other stuff for ex. a scroll-prallalex effect.

Answer (score 18):

for simple and not complicated code just use this code in the css file

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it's better to use it for html as well , like Vinay Yadav suggest `html,body{ overflow-x: hidden;
}`

Answer (score 3):

For mobile view in `@media (your max/min width)` for html and body tag add `overflow-x: hidden`.

Try this:

```
html, body {
  // Smooth scroll always for html tag
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  // scroll-snap-type: y; // <-- snap in y axis
}

// mobile 
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This white space problem had been bugging me and I was doing the usual searches for ideas when I came across this thread. The way I fixed mine.. (back story- everything was fine and then I made some css changes, several days later I noticed the white space.) The white space was not to the right of the header on all pages, only certain ones- that’s how I knew it was a div issue. Made a small list of elements that were not on the good pages, but present on white space pages, letting me narrow things down a bit)

I simply used the Chrome inspector and the down arrow on the main affected page elements tab. While scrolling along with what was getting highlighted, I came across a div for the Wordpress like button, which I had set a Margin for instead of padding. This was enough to move the edge of the div to white space up the right side of the whole page, including the header.

I think the reason the white space doesn’t show up when you inspector it is because it doesn’t actually “exist”, for want of a better word, other than in the exclusively affected div, which in my case was a box only 20-30px in height way down the bottom of the page.

I tried the overflow-x/hidden command, while it did work for me, I found that it created an issue where the mobile device scrolling was jittery and sometimes wouldn’t start scrolling at all, just a move and a bounce back to start point. So that was no good obv! I would say to anyone having this problem that the inspector and finding the div, rather than hiding the overflow is the most trouble free way to go.

Hope that gives someone a pointer! Cheers :)

D

Answer (score 2):

## Sticky top bar

If you want to have (position) `sicky` top bar then `hidden` value will break it. So use `clip` instead.

```js
html,body{
    overflow-x: clip;
}
```

Example with `clip`

```css
html,body { 
  overflow-x: clip;
}

body {margin:0;}

.topBar {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  font-size: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, red);  
}

.rightBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 100px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div> Top bar</div>
</div>

<div>


<div class="content">
  <div>My content</div>
  <div class="rightBox">it goes out</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If we use `hidden` in above snippet - then it will broke our `sticky` topbar:

```css
html,body { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {margin:0;}

.topBar {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  font-size: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, red);  
}

.rightBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 100px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div> Top bar</div>
</div>

<div>


<div class="content">
  <div>My content</div>  
  <div class="rightBox">it goes out</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried all the steps given by others here and it did not work. Funny enough even inspecting the elements did not show what exactly was the problem. Took me a while then I started removing and adding back some major elements of my page. Turned out it was a div that had a rogue element in it.

Point is, you may have to just iterate over and over before you land a solution. Try removing some major suspect elements , save, reload and see if it solves it, gradually you will find the culprit