# White space on right side of page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with unwanted free space on right side of my webpage. Here is my webpage : 
[image: right side]

I add these code

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

and it's solved my problem but, it disable footer icons on webpage so how can i do this?

Here is webpage :

[webpage url](http://www.fikirfabrika.org)

Comment: your ``footer`` ``div class"=row"`` tag is not within the ``container`` tag

Comment: close the ``container`` div before the ``</footer>`` tag closeing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012482/unwanted-white-space-on-right-side-in-mobile-view
check this answer it might help you

Answer (score 9):

One of your elements it's causing that margin. To find out you can set all elements outline border for 1px red and then fix it.

```
*{
 outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner in web development and your suggestion helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add this code but instead you need to correct a HTML code in the footer part. actually it's looking like this

```html
<footer id="site-footer" class="footer ">
  <div class="container">
  </div> <!-- issue here !!-->
  <div class="row" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="contacts-item">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You have closed the div of the **container** badly, it should be closed after the **row** div. That's why you are having the white space, as the row class add negative margin that are corrected by the container.

Comment: ok, i change this but it allready there. these codes not make change

Comment: i still see the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake in your HTML `footer > container` closing tag**

*Edited another mistake*

```
//1: header mistake - Position  
//the problem is position: relative in header media query on the theme-styles.css

   .header @media (max-width: 768px){
     /* position: relative; */ /*remove this*/
        animation: none !important;
        padding: 0px 0;
    }

//2: footer mistake - container closing tag
    <footer id="site-footer" class="footer ">
       <div class="container">
            //container closed here
       </div>//remove this close tag
           <div class="row>"---</div>
           <div class="sub-footer large">---</div>

      </div>//container close here
   </footer>
```

Comment: ok, i change this but it allready there. these codes not make change

Comment: I have checked the mistake using your linked  [web page](http://fikirfabrika.org/). by inspecting it's worked

Comment: i know it's looks like worked but, in mobile phone, whitespace allready there.

Comment: I checked the problem is in your header section

Comment: remove ``position:relative`` property in ``.header (max-width: 570px){--}`` on ``theme-styles.css`` file

Comment: thanks for help, i change this. but still header gives this whitespace. Please help me again ?

Comment: I am always checking them on the website, I think error is in your script